# Displaying an XML composite element in DGV

Tags: java, c#, xml, serialization

The case looks like I've created an API in JAVA that serializes an XML file. The class I'm trying to get looks like:

```
public class Cassette {
           private Integer upper;
           private Integer lower;


           public Cassette() {
        }

        public Cassette(Integer upper, Integer lower) {
            this.upper = upper;
            this.lower = lower;
        }


        public Integer getUpper() {
            return upper;
        }

        public void setUpper(Integer upper) {
            this.upper = upper;
        }

        public Integer getLower() {
            return lower;
        }

        public void setLower(Integer lower) {
            this.lower = lower;
        }   


               @Override
               public String toString() {
               return ""+ upper + "-" + lower + "\n\r";
           }
       }
```

I am trying to force a C # client to display a result in the DGV window in the format: number - number e.g. 30-11.
I came to the point where I manage to display the result but in the title of the column. As a value in the column field I still get an error that I *can not convert System.String to BooksClient.BIKE.cassette*. Just something like "BooksClient.BIKE.cassette" appears to me in the column and I would like to display the exact value.
I'm adding my C # code. I also have a screen with an error. Unfortunately in Polish. Is anyone able to tell me how to do it?

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
{

 if (dataGridView1.Columns[i].HeaderText=="cassette")
   {

    cassette = bike[i].cassette.upper + " - " + bike[i].cassette.lower;
    Console.WriteLine(cassette);

   object newValue = 
   TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(String)).ConvertTo(cassette, 
   typeof(BooksClient.BIKE.cassette));

   dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[i].Value = newValue;

       }
     }
```

Comment: Change from  : object newValue to : string newValue so the compiler gives you the error instead getting an error at run time.

Comment: string newValue = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(String)).ConvertTo(cassette, typeof(BooksClient.BIKE.cassette)); ? You can not implicitly convert "object" to "string". There is an explicit conversion (is there no missing projection?). I do not think so?

Comment: The compile error message is correct.  Fix the compiler error and the code will work.

Comment: then you have an idea how to fix this error? I try in different ways and I still get it :(

Comment: cassette is a class and you are converting to a string.  Break the instruction up to multiple instructions..  Then compiler will clearly indicate when you have an error.

Comment: The mistake is that JAVA has sent the column type as Cassette. And it can not be converted to String once the columns have been created. I even thought about the force solution - remove the loaded column and insert a new String column in its place. Unless you can convert the type of columns? I tried but it gives me nothing.

Comment: You need to parse or De-Serialize the JAVA to get the data before converting to XML.  The net library will not cast a JSON string to XML without writing the code.